# kibana for sql database

Tags: sql, visualization, dashboard, kibana

I need to build a kibana like dashboard over a sql database. Is this possible? or is there an alternative as easy as kibana (in term of integration) for sql?

Answer (score 9):

Siren ( http://siren.io ) is an extended Kibana  which has support for connecting directly to SQL (or other APIs) and create filters and analytics.

Check it out

Answer (score 5):

There is a blog about how to index SQL databases in Elasticsearch here:
http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2014/01/30/elasticsearch-indexing-sql-databases-the-easy-way/

Once you get it indexed, you can set up your Kibana to view your data.

You can also find more options suggested here:
http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/377151-generate-a-dashboard-from-sql-database

Answer (score 3):

this could be an alternative for you- https://github.com/KPIWatchdog/DBconnector
creates an API to the tool where you can create queries, visualise data, prepare dashboards and share to others. Depending on the number of metrics, you can opt for free plan or small monthly fee.